# Xamarin Derived UIControl TouchUpInside event isn't working

Tags: c#, ios, events, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to set an `TouchUpInside` event to my class that inherit from `UIControl`.

First, I've tried to set the event to each control separately, in the same class, and it's also not working.
Than, I've tried to set the event from the window that present this UIControl, but also isn't working.

The class drawing two controls, `Button` and `TextField`:

```
public class SingleItemView : UIControl
{
    public UIButton RadioButton { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        this.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

        RadioButton = new UIButton(rect);
        RadioButton.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("images/Unknown_Gray.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
        RadioButton.HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        this.AddSubview(RadioButton);

        var textField = new UITextField(new RectangleF(rect.X + 25, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height));
        textField.Placeholder = "Place Holder is here";
        this.AddSubview(textField);
    }   
}
```

The `ViewController` that signs the event:

```
public class ItmesView : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var item = new SingleItemView();
        item.Draw(new RectangleF(10, 60, 50, 30));
        item.TouchUpInside += item_TouchUpInside;
        this.View.AddSubview(item); 
    }
}
```

None of the events I've tried isn't working, any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Err, that code above is just wrong. Not syntactically but semantically. You're creating instances of `UIButton` and `UITextField` on every redraw of the UI. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve but you should start with the basics of subclassing and then move on to the Xamarin iOS APIs.

Comment: i'm trying to create a window with multiple SingleItemView. Something like UITableView, but instead of UITableViewCell, it should be SingleItemView. If you have suggestion for that, I will appreciate that. Thanks.